# Как наложить картинку NSImage на фигуру SCNGeometry?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Мне дали задание установить текстуру на октаэдр. Это должна быть именно картинка.
Прочитал много советов, как бы это сделать. Особенно много рассказывают про UIKit и класс UIImage, но сам использую AppKit и класс NSImage — аналог для макос. И ничто мне не помогло. Может быть, не понимаю чего-то фундаментального или наоборот делаю совсем глупую ошибку.

Опишу свой алгоритм действий. Сначала добавил картинку с названием "sims.jpg" в папку проекта и папку art.scnassets. А потом ещё добавил её туда и туда вот так: File → Add files to "art.scnassets". С папкой Assets.xcassets ничего не делал.

Вот так создаётся фигура:

```
func createOctahedron() {

   let vertices: [SCNVector3] = [
       SCNVector3(0, 1, 0),
       SCNVector3(-0.5, 0, 0.5),
       SCNVector3(0.5, 0, 0.5),
       SCNVector3(0.5, 0, -0.5),
       SCNVector3(-0.5, 0, -0.5),
       SCNVector3(0, -1, 0)
   ]

   let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)

   let indices: [UInt16] = [
       0, 1, 2,
       2, 3, 0,
       3, 4, 0,
       4, 1, 0,
       1, 5, 2,
       2, 5, 3,
       3, 5, 4,
       4, 5, 1
   ]

   let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .triangles)
   let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
   let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)

   node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.green // назначаем цвет октаэдру

   let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
   scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

   let rotateAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: .pi, z: 0, duration: 5))
   node.runAction(rotateAction)
}
```

[Весь код целиком](https://pastebin.com/vw4CUYRm) на всякий случай.

Пробовал добавить картинку так:

```
let imageMaterial = SCNMaterial()
let image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("sims"))
imageMaterial.diffuse.contents = image
geometry.materials = [imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial, imageMaterial]
```

И так:

```
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("sims"))
```

И ещё другими способами. Может быть, её надо как-то дополнительно привязывать к вершинам фигуры? Помогите, пожалуйста. Первый раз взаимодействую со свифтом. Пока что Xcode выдаёт просто белый вращающийся октаэдр (или зелёный — это я нашёл, как сделать), а ошибок не выдаёт. Но мне нужно именно шоб с картинкой на гранях

Comment: В общем, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881717/how-do-i-use-an-nsimage-as-material-of-an-scngeometry-shape-correctly) сам себе ответил  Оказывается, для такого рода текстуры нужен дополнительный массив с координатами. А вот [рабочий код](https://pastebin.com/cDfR0sqi) на всякий случай